# Batch Test class not calling execute method

Tags: apex, batch, code-coverage

I have created below batch apex class. I have also created test class for this. But this test class is only covering 27% of batch apex class. Also, it is not calling execute method of batch apex class.

Batch Apex class:

---

```
global class LeadDuplicateRemove implements Database.Batchable < sObject > {


    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator('select Id, CreatedDate, Phone, Status, Email from Lead Where convertedbusiness__c != null and LeadAudit__c = null  and isDeleted = false order by CreatedDate ASC Limit 1');
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List < Lead > scope) {
        for (Lead lead: scope) {
            Database.QueryLocator leadQueryLocator = Database.getQueryLocator([Select Id, CreatedDate, Phone, Status, Email from Lead where convertedbusiness__c != null and LeadAudit__c = '1' and isDeleted = false order by CreatedDate ASC Limit 1]);

            Database.QueryLocatorIterator iterator = leadQueryLocator.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Lead leadObj = (Lead) iterator.next();

                if(lead.ConvertedBusiness__c == leadObj.ConvertedBusiness__c){
                    lead.ConvertedBusiness__c = null;
                }
            }
        } 
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    }
}
```

### Test class:

```
@isTest global class LeadDuplicateRemoveTest {
    @testSetup 
    global static void setup() {

        Lead lead1 = new Lead(LastName='testlead1 ', RAF_Nurture_Campaign__c = 'None',
                              company='test', Email='testemai@email.com.invalid',Phone = '1111111111',Status ='Completed');

        insert lead1;
        insert new Lead(LastName='testlead1', RAF_Nurture_Campaign__c = 'None',
                               company='Vtest', Email='testemai@email.com.invalid',Phone = '222222',Status ='Open');

    }
    @isTest global static void TestRun() {         
        Test.startTest();
        Database.executeBatch(new LeadDuplicateRemove());
        Test.stopTest();

    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have the filter `convertedbusiness__c != null` but when you are creating the lead, you are not setting this.

```
Lead lead1 = new Lead(convertedbusiness__c= ??, LastName='testlead1 ', RAF_Nurture_Campaign__c = 'None',
                          company='test', Email='testemai@email.com.invalid',Phone = '1111111111',Status ='Completed');
```

As no records are returned from `start` method, it is not even invoking `execute` method

**Note:**

Also, you have query locator and iterator inside execute - which is not needed. You are returning leads where `LeadAudit__c = null` and again processing on records where `LeadAudit__c = '1'`. You might as well remove the filter `LeadAudit__c = null` from `start` method and process the records inside execute without iterator.

Comment: Also, there's no DML operation, so changes won't be persisted in execute method.

Comment: +1. 
Reason database query iterator inside execute method is I am comparing leads records leadautit__c = null received in start methods to lead records with leadaudit__c = '1'. Isn't this right way to do ?

Comment: You can get the records without lead audit filter. Inside execute method scope you get both types of records which you can compare. No need of any query again

Comment: But the thing is I want to compare only those leadaudit = null records to leadaudit = 1. 

if i keep leadaudit = null in start than it will will only fetch those leads in scope. So that I can compare each of that record with leadauit =1 record in execute method. 

Am i doing anything wrong here ?